# Can't start mongodb service

Tags: mongodb, windows-services

I just instaled mongo 3. And tried to run it as windows server but receive error

```
The MongoDB 3.0 service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
Cannot create another system semaphore.
```

Can't find any info about that error and mongodb.

Comment: I just installed also Mongo and got same error. Did you find out what is the problem?

Comment: Yes, in my case problem was in hard drive available space. Need more than 3 GB

Comment: The 3GB problem was mine too

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check mongodb logs. In my case mongodb could not find directory from mongod.cfg

Comment: Yes, I had same directory missing problem

Answer (score 19):

In my case it appered to be mongod.lock issue after unexpected shutdown.

```
Detected unclean shutdown - E:\MongoDb\Databases\mongod.lock is not empty.
```

I deleted E:\MongoDb\Databases\mongod.lock and mongo successfuly started.

Answer (score 3):

In **Windows**:

there is an effective method to solve this issue.

Firstly, try to delete the file `storage.bson` under the folder "D:\mongodb\data", or the corresponding path in your PC.

If the **issue still exists**, try following steps in order.

For example mongoDB version 3.6 is installed, and the install path of MongoDB is "D:\Program Files\MongoDB".

Create folder `D:\mongodb\logs`, then create file `mongodb.log` inside this folder.

Run cmd.exe as **administrator**,

```
D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>taskkill /F /IM mongod.exe
D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongod.exe --logpath D:\mongodb\logs\mongodb.log --logappend --dbpath D:\mongodb\data --directoryperdb --serviceName MongoDB --remove
D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongod --logpath "D:\mongodb\logs\mongodb.log" --logappend --dbpath "D:\mongodb\data" --directoryperdb --serviceName "MongoDB" --serviceDisplayName "MongoDB" --install
```

Remove these two files `mongod.lock` and `storage.bson` under the folder "D:\mongodb\data".

Then type `net start MongoDB` in the cmd using administrator privilege, the issue will be solved.

Comment: Thanks ... storage.bson was not letting me start the service.

Answer (score 2):

This happened for me a couple times because my Mac crashed which resulted in unclean shutdown of Parallels and my Mongo instance. mongod.lock was not empty.

This was on a development server so I didn't have backups. I was able to repair by using

```
mongod --repair --repairpath <path to your mongo data>
```

More instructions [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/)

Answer (score 2):

After installing the .msi on Windows 10 in Program Files, I created the service for a different data location C:\Mongo\Data\DB

The Service installed correctly but didn't start with error "Cannot create another system semaphore" because:

**I hadn't created the required folder structure.**  Simple as that - d'oh!

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Also check permissions for dbpath and logpath.  In my case I had configured mongo as a service running as Network Service, but, hadn't given Network Service write access to those directories.

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone else, for me it was that I had started mongod.exe manually in a command prompt window so the windows service couldn't run mongod.exe on the same port already in use. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and in my case the config was wrong. This error from event viewer is not very helpful and mostly confusing so everyone should check mongo logs first.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't have enough space on disc C: where MongoDB was installed. After making some space -- mongod.exe successfully started.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, another instance of MongoDB was running in command prompt on the same port.

Answer (score 0):

For me, on a fresh install of MongoDB v4.0.3 on Windows 10 Pro, the install failed to start the mongo service at the end.

Trying to start mongod from the command prompt, pointed to the correct `mongodb.cfg` config, gave me the error:

> Unrecognized option: mp

I ripped open the config and searched for "mp", to find the last 2 lines of the file:

```
#snmp:
mp:
```

I threw a # in front of that last line and tried again, and the service started fine.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯