# Error while installing MongoDB as windows service

Tags: mongodb, windows-services

I tried installing [MongoDB 3. X version as windows service](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/). I executed following commands:

```
mkdir c:\data\db
mkdir c:\data\log
echo logpath=c:\data\log\mongod.log> "C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg"
echo dbpath=c:\data\db>> "C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg"
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg\"" DisplayName= "MongoDB" start= "auto"
```

after executing these commands I got following message:

```
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
```

But I was unable to start the windows service. Everytime, I tried installing MongoDB as windows service, it threw some error.

Then I followed [this post](http://www.journaldev.com/6128/how-to-install-start-and-remove-mongodb-on-windows): but I am still getting errors.

Please see below image for more information.
[image]

`Event log` under `System` is showing following error: `The MongoDB service terminated with service-specific error Cannot create another system semaphore..`

Earlier I had installed MongoDB v 2.6 & I was able to install it successfully as windows service. I wonder if I need a different approach to install version 3.X.

Comment: Is there nothing in the event log?

Comment: @Nattrass: I am not sure what message was logged in event view after the first method failed. But the second approach is shwoing `The MongoDB service terminated with service-specific error Cannot create another system semaphore..` error in event log under system

Comment: Is there more to that event? It looks like you've truncated something off the end. Or did it really end  with two ..'s

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143414/cant-start-mongodb-service

Answer (score 1):

I have now installed mongodb 2.6. and followed these instructions.

I suggest extracting the Mongo installation to `c:\mongodb.`

Create the `c:\mongodb\logs` and the `c:\mongodb\data\db` directories.

Then browse the the `c:\mongodb\bin` directory and run the following to remove the service (if you've installed it!):

```
mongod --remove
```

Then install the service, specifying the log and data directories:

```
mongod --logpath c:\mongodb\logs\mongo.log --dbpath c:\mongodb\data\db --directoryperdb --install
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by removing `mongod.lock` and `storage.bson` files under `/data/db`.