# MongoDb not getting installed in win 10

Tags: mongodb

While installing MongoDB in win 10, I'm getting:

> error code:100

When I'm entering `>net start MongoDB`, it shows

> The mongoDB service couldnt be started.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't start mongodb service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143414/cant-start-mongodb-service)

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143414/cant-start-mongodb-service

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your question is the same as below topic:
[MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523321/mongoerror-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-127017)
but I had problem with running mongodb in window and this topic helped me to solve it.