# MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb

I'm using NodeJS wih MongoDB using mongodb package. When I run mongod command it works fine and gives "waiting for connection on port 27017". So, mongod seems to be working. But MongoClient does not work and gives error when I run node index.js command-

```
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

[image]

I have install mongo db 3.4 and my code is-

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var dburl       =   "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";
MongoClient.connect(dburl, function(err, db) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log('db connected');
  db.close();
});
```

I have created data/db directories on root and given write permissions.
mongod.conf file takes db path as-

storage:
dbPath: /var/lib/mongo

But it seems that it is actually taking db path as data/db and not var/lib/mongo

It working earlier but suddenly stopped.

Comment: Go inside location C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin and run mongod.exe and try again

Comment: Thanks. But I am on amazon linux server. How to test there?

Comment: replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 and try. not sure about the result but try and update us. and also try with running below command from terminal ,sudo service mongod start

Comment: I already tried this, didn't work.
sudo service mongod start gives error-

Starting mongod (via systemctl):  Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: I am really surprised how many answer provide a **Windows** solution (and they are even top rated) despite this question clearly refers to Linux.

Comment: This happened to me when I forgot to start the docker instance I was using with mongo.

Comment: Try manually stopping the server and starting again. I also faced the same problem on my Mac M1. Although mongodb was running but the mongoose could not connect to it.

Comment: On Mac I replaced localhost with 127.0.0.1 ,  it works.

Comment: @HarshitGangwar, Any help? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: To future users: Please do not take this question as a precedent for usage of images. Images should not be used when the image is of text that could be written in the post. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Nodejs driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver)

Answer (score 328):

My apps stopped working after upgrading from Node.js 14 to 17.

The error I got was:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
```

The solution was simply replacing `localhost` by `0.0.0.0`. I.e. in my source code I had to change:

```
const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
```

to:

```
const uri = "mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/";
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
```

Comment: MongoDB seems to be not compatible with NodeJS v17. It should be listening on IPv6 "::1" by default and it would work with v17 without any problem.

Comment: What makes `mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/` ?, try to connect to every ip?

Comment: for me replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 worked, thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, brother. Can you please tell me why this error occurred? why localhost is not working

Comment: I noticed (with `ping localhost`) that the localhost of my freshly installed OS points to ::1 (which is ipv6) rather than 127.0.0.1 like it used to previously. That probably means that using `mongodb://localhost:27017/` probably will make node try to connect via ipv6, which mongo probably is not listening to.

Comment: mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/ worked for me 

Comment: 0.0.0.0 worked for me too. Never seen something this stupid.

Comment: @pagenotfound thank you so much! I surfed the web for hours and you saved my head and my time! Thank and Thank you and Thank you!!!

Comment: Thank you so much, bro. I was banging my head for a week. All the tutorials show the same localhost:27017
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db_name works for me

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been searching for this for three days. I also had another issue before which was not being able to connect to the MongoDB even.
and just wasting my time on their website

Mac issue not finding the data/db

mongod --dbpath=/Users/youUserName/data/db

Comment: It happened to me too, after I upgraded from `node 16` to `node 18`. I used `127.0.0.1` and it worked. I don't know why that happened in the first place though! Thank you anyway

Comment: In addition, 127.0.0.1 also works, Thanks

Comment: This worked for me on WIndows 10

Comment: I spent hours resolving this issue and changing `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` worked for me. 
Thanks a lot, brother!!

Comment: I simply lost 4 hours of searching and finally changing from `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` worked at my end

Comment: Wow. Surprised with this fix. +1

Comment: very helpful. but need to know more informations about the error

Comment: I don't think `0.0.0.0` is the perfect solution, because IP `0.0.0.0` should/cannot be used as destination address (see [0.0.0.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)). Better use IP `127.0.0.1` or the real hostname or bind the IPv6 Address, see [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Nodejs driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver/74610881#74610881) It also explains why `localhost` does not work

Answer (score 234):

This happened probably because the **MongoDB** service isn't started. Follow the below steps to start it:

1. Press the **Windows + R** keys on your keyboard to open the Run
   window. Type **services.msc** and hit Enter on your keyboard or
   click/tap the OK button. A new window opens up.
2. Search **MongoDB.exe**. Right click on it and select *Start*.

The server will start. Now execute `npm start` again and the code might work this time.

Comment: For windows 10 path is Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools

Comment: If you can't click _Start_, right click MongoDB, enter _Properties_ and change _Startup Type_ to _Manual_

Comment: How do you do this on "macOS Ventura 13.2" ?

Comment: The screenshot clearly shows a Linux environment, not Windows.

Answer (score 29):

I've forgot to start MongoDB at all.
Go to separate tab in terminal and type:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Comment: How can I run this command automatically on restart? Right now I have to run this command each time I restart.

Comment: not working for me.

Comment: @Khushalsharma   `sudo  systemctl enable mongod`

Answer (score 26):

Search **services.msc** in your device and click start to run the **mongoDB server**

[image]

After started running MongoDB server you will able to run your program

Comment: The screenshot clearly shows a Linux environment, not Windows.

Answer (score 21):

For windows - just go to Mongodb folder
 (ex : C:\ProgramFiles\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin) and open cmd in the folder and type
"mongod.exe --dbpath c:\data\db"

if c:\data\db folder doesn't exist then create it by yourself and run above command again.

All should work fine by now.))

Comment: @nikhilsugandh - really? The screenshot clearly shows a Linux environment, not Windows.

Answer (score 21):

Instead of this:

```
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
```

Use this:

```
const url = "mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017";
```

Comment: This one solve my problem in my case

Answer (score 19):

**For Windows users**.

This happens because the MondgDB server is stopped.
to fix this you can,

1. 1 search for Services ,for that search using the left bottom corner
   search option.

   2 then there is a gear icon named with 'Services'.

   3 after clicking that you will get a window with lot of services

   4 scroll down and you will find 'MongoDB server (MongoDB)'.

   5 so you will see that there is an option to start the service.

   6 start it.
2. 1 then open your command prompt.

   2 type `mongod`

now you can connect to your server.

this steps also working fine if your sql server service down. (find sql server services)

Answer (score 19):

**Method 1**

> If It’s MAC OS, run following command and try again:

```
brew services restart mongodb-community
```

> Stopping mongodb-community... (might take a while)
> ==> Successfully stopped mongodb-community (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
> ==> Successfully started mongodb-community (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)

Comment: Error: No available formula with the name "mongodb-community". Did you mean mongodb-atlas-cli?

Comment: Is there any other method

Answer (score 13):

For Ubuntu users run
`sudo systemctl restart mongod`

Comment: Finally, someone wrote the instruction for Ubuntu, and it worked immediately for my Ubuntu 22.04, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12):

I had below error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

In my case, this issue occurred since MongoDB is not installed at all.

The solution was to install MongoDB from below location:
  https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community

After installing the `ECONNREFUSED` error did not appear again.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 12):

I just found a solution in the internet ,
If you are using latest nodejs (v17.x) , then try updating mongodb url from localhost to 127.0.0.1

ref: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongooseserverselectionerror-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-1-27017/123421/3

Answer (score 10):

If you already installed "MongoDB", if you accidentally exit from the MongoDB server, then "restart your system".

This method solved for me...

[On Windows only]

And also another method is there:

press:

```
Windows + R
```

type:

```
services.msc
```

and click "ok", it opens
"services" window, and then search for "MongoDB Server" in the list.
After you find "MongoDB Server", right-click and choose "start" from the pop-up menu.

The MongoDb Server will start running.

Hope it works!!

Answer (score 9):

Try to start mongoDB server by giving the --dbpath with mongod.

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo/data/db &
```

'&' in the last will start the mongodb server as service on your server.

Hope it Works.

Comment: No, it does not. `&` puts the program into background, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745164/difference-between-a-service-and-a-process-which-is-running-in-a-background-by

Answer (score 7):

Press CTRL+ALT+DELETE/task manager , then go to services , find MongoDB , right click on it. start. go back to terminal . npm start it will work.

Comment: easy solution, it works on my windows 10. thank you

Answer (score 7):

You can run **`Cmd as administrator`** and write this command to start **`Mongodb service`**:

```
 net start MongoDB
```

OR

1. Click window key + r key
2. Type services.msc and press ok
3. Wait open service
4. Search mongodb
5. Click right key and start press
   [image: Run MongoDB service]

and reopen mongodb

Answer (score 6):

On a mac I had to run `brew services start mongodb-community@4.4`

Check: [Install MongoDB Community Edition on macOS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)

Comment: Error: No available formula with the name "mongodb-community@4.4".

Comment: It looks like I need to update the answer. Could you please try: `brew services start mongodb-community@6.0`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error because i had not installed mongoDB.
Make sure that you have mongodb installed and if not, you can download it from here https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community

Comment: If you have it installed and are still having said problem, you forgot to start the services

Comment: "install mongodb" is not an answer for sure...people who post this are users of MongoDB.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows users:
**Mongo version 4.4**
Use following commands:
`NET STOP MONGODB` – To stop MongoDB as a service,if this returns "mongoDb service is not running then use below command to start service"
`NET START MONGODB` – To start MongoDB as a service.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

just start the mongo server from terminal

Ubuntu -

```
     sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Comment: thx matte. in my case, I was forgetting to run it as `sudo`.

Comment: Solved my problem on Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED ANSWER FOR THIS QUESTION !!**

So I tried everything in this forum. but no result!(From my side). so i tried this one:

1)go to control panel

2)Select System and Security and choose last option :Administrative tools.

3)Select Services

4)Search for **MongoDB Server (MongoDB)**

5)Right click on it and click on run.

6)and close the Services blindly

7)last but not least,change your mongodb url to **mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/**

8)Restart your server and that worked for me!.

9)So i tried this by combining 2 answers in this forum !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

**I faced the same error then I found that If you are using the latest nodejs (v17.x), then try updating the MongoDB URL from localhost to 127.0.0.1
This worked for me.**

Answer (score 3):

If you use `MongoDb Compass` make sure that you have installed `MongoDB Community Server`.

Comment: haha, Yes. this is underrated Ans.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue on windows 10. I just uninstall MongoDB and installed it again and it started working. It solved my problem.

Comment: It is better to comment on your short answers and ideas like other friends

Comment: This is because the service was disabled. Just open Services > Enable and Start mongod service. You can achieve the same using the command line. Just consult the documentation for exact syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I debugged this same error on my own for over 5 hours. Eventually it worked out for me. Below is a check list of items to make sure they are correct before using Mongoose.

- MongoDB is installed on your system
- MongoDB is running as a service before you use `npm run start`
- The mongoose code does not have any syntax errors
- Use promises `.then()` in the connect function for mongoose
- If you are using `localhost` in URL, try switching it with `0.0.0.0` or vice versa

Once you have done all this, run the command `node run start` and hopefully this should work now. To verify, go to mongoDB and see the newly created database.

Below is a sample code for MongoDB and Mongoose that worked for me.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const myFunc = () => {
    const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: String
    });

    const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

    const userObject = new User({
        name: 'Abhishek'
    });

    userObject.save((err, data) => {
        if (err)
            console.log('Error in saving = ' + err);
        if (data)
            console.log('Saved to DB = ' + data)
    }
    );
};

mongoose
    .connect("mongodb://0.0.0.0/userdb")
    .then(myFunc(), err => console.log(`Error = ${err}`));
```

Answer (score 2):

Check where your .sock file is located. For my case, it was in /tmp folder.

Then run the following commands.

```
chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

sudo systemctl start mongod

mongosh
```

This worked for me.

[For more reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823288/mongodb-loads-but-breaks-returning-status-14#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%20mongo%2Ddocs,performing%20a%20clean%20shut%20down.%22)

Answer (score 2):

I was getting same error. I was doing everything right like path variables and stating mongodb before running code. Replacing localhost with IP i.e 127.0.0.1 in connection code solved for me.

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/test', {useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true});

Answer (score 2):

From MongoDB Forums

[MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 Answer](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongooseserverselectionerror-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-1-27017/123421/5)

Just change the "URI" from

```
mongodb://localhost:27017
```

to

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
```

Comment: or

    `mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017`

Answer (score 1):

most probably your mongo db service is not started. 
For ubuntu :  `sudo service mongod start`
For windows : go to services and start the MongoDB service

also install link for mondoDB service https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community

I had this problem and i solved it thanks to this man's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47433551/7917608

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that your mongo DB is set Automatic and running at Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Services like below. That way you wont have to start mongod.exe manually each time.

[image]

Comment: that has nothing to do with the OPs question.

Comment: this work for me in windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem today.. and has been searching for answers.. I am on Ubuntu... however, I could not find the correct one that works on this thread.. after much research the following worked for me finally!! :)

First, after running

```
mongod dbpath
```

if appeared that mongodb was looking for the data/db directory.. which was missing in my installed mongodb app.. so I ran the following commands:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db
```

then run,

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER /data/db
```

chown - changes ownership of files/dirs. Ie. owner of the file/dir changes to the specified one, but it doesn't modify permissions. As detailed here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402062/how-are-chown-and-chmod-command-different-in-the-given-operation

Finally, run

```
`$ sudo systemctl enable mongod.service
```

It will give a message: Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mongod.service → /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service and started the service.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on WSL and trying to access MongoDB from Windows, then you have to install Mongo for WSL.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue with Node.js v17 under Windows.
Found the issue open on mongoose github with some solutions: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10917

I had to **either** use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in the mongoose.connect function, which worked.

**Or** edit the config file with admin rights notepad. Open admin cmd, go to `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin` folder, enter command `notepad mongod.cfg` then edit:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  ipv6: true
```

I had to remove `bindIp: 127.0.0.1`, leaving only port and ipv6, otherwise database wouldn't connect even with `ipv6: true`.
Then restart mongodb service with windows task manager -> services -> mongodb, and using localhost would work.

Apparently using `mongod://0.0.0.0:27017/` is not safe: [mongodb.conf bind_ip = 127.0.0.1 does not work but 0.0.0.0 works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588876/mongodb-conf-bind-ip-127-0-0-1-does-not-work-but-0-0-0-0-works)

Answer (score 1):

i faced this problem when i updated my Node js from version `16.18.0` to `18.12.0`

No need to change your URI
you have to just go to your windows service and find mongo db,
once it will appear,
just stop the service
and start again
thats it

Answer (score 1):

If you use mac and you want to start mongodb compass you need to start mongo service.

if you haven't mongo service

1. `brew tap mongodb/brew`
2. `brew install mongodb-community`
3. `brew services start mongodb-community`

OR `brew services restart mongodb-community`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to continue running your DB process (by running `mongod`) while running your node server.

Answer (score 0):

because you didn't start mongod process before you try starting mongo shell.

Start mongod server

```
mongod
```

Open another terminal window

Start mongo shell

```
mongo
```

Comment: this is only for windows machine

Answer (score 0):

In my particular instance, I was connected to a VPN and that was blocking the localhost connection to MongoDB somehow. It worked when I disconnected my VPN. It's a special case, but good to know nonetheless. So anything impeding your network connectivity, Get that fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to start mongod service and then make connection.
To do so, open your terminal (powershell in Windows) and write command mongod
[image]

Now connect using MongoDB compass it will work

Answer (score 0):

Add **family: 4** as a option. 
*family* - Whether to connect using IPv4 or IPv6. This option is passed to Node.js' dns.lookup() function. If you don't specify this option, the MongoDB driver will try IPv6 first and then IPv4 if IPv6 fails. If your mongoose. connect(uri) call takes a long time, try mongoose.connect(uri, { family: 4 })

```
export const connectWithDb =()=>{
    mongoose.connect(uri,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true,family: 4}).then(db => console.log('DB is connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same ERROR.

> connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 Connection Failed!

Because I have updated my node version. I rollback to the last version of node.js then it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Add follwing code in app.js:**

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')

// Create Instance of MongoClient for mongodb
const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017')

// Connect to database
client.connect()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected Successfully!')
        
        //Close the database connection
        console.log('Exiting..')
        client.close()
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('Failed to connect!', error))
```

Source: [Connect MongoDB with Node JS](https://www.scaler.com/topics/nodejs/connect-mongodb-with-node-js/)

Answer (score 0):

After I install the [MongoDB Community Server](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community) my problem was solved. ✔️

Answer (score 0):

At first, you must be **installed the MongoDB Community version** from here :
https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community/releases

then Start the MongoDB Service

***Define MongoDB URL in .env:***

```
 MONGO_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/eshop
```

***then create config/db.js***

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDB = async () => {
  mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
  const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  console.log(`MongoDB connected :${conn.connection.host}`.underline.cyan);
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

**then server.js**

```
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
```

**then run :**

```
connectDB();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it. The error occurs because your MongoDB server is not running. You need to start the MongoDB server. Use the following steps to do it.

1. Search the `Services` app on the search bar and open it.
2. Scroll down and find the `MongoDB server`
3. Right-click on it.
4. Select `start`.
5. Now the server is started.

Try to re-run. Now it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu this worked for me

```
mkdir $HOME/data
mongod --dbpath $HOME/data
```

then just run mongo or Compass

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on Windows.

**Ctrl+C to close mongod, and start mongod again.**

Am not sure, but it seems that initially mongod was working opening and closing connections.  Then, it was not able to close some earlier connections and reached limit for opened ones.  After restarting mongod, it works again.

Answer (score -1):

If you are a windows user, right click on Start and open Windows Powershell(Run as administartor). Then type

```
mongod
```

That's it.
Your database will surely get connected!

Comment: He already has said that he is not a windows user and is on an Amazon linux instance.