# Difference between a service and a process which is running in a background by & command

Tags: linux, service, operating-system, background-process

I'm a student in CS who recently became a big fan of Linux.

I found out that there are two types of ways running a process in a background.

First, a user explicitly start a process in a shell with & command.

```
./main &
```

Second, the processes which are found by **service --status-all** command.

```
service --status-all
```

In my case, I can find there are 'bluetooth', 'redis-server', 'mosquitto', ...

I think they are the same in that both are running in a background.

But I want to know more accurate and detailed difference between them if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is started on your local term and "pushed" on background. You can see it with the `jobs` command. Pushing in forground with `fg` command for example.
The first command was killed when you close your current term.

The second is a daemon, not assingned to a terminal. It run every time

Comment: When I types the [alt+ctrl+T] command, new terminal pops. Then this new terminal is also process created by fork() internally? If so, whenever I types run command for some programs on the terminal, the terminal process also forks the process for them. That is why first command was killed when I close the current term. But second one belongs to  the init process or something(?) so it run every time. Then the main difference is where it is forked from. Am I right???