# Unable to connect the mongodb server while using NodeJS

Tags: mongodb

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\javascriptApps\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:428:30)

Comment: Please follow proper question format rather than just copy pasting the error as a question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523321/mongoerror-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-127017)

Answer (score 2):

The error ECONNREFUSED is nothing but the connection have been refused. There is no process endpoint listening on local 127.0.0.1:27017

Before connecting to the database, make sure to install mongodb and  **start the database server**. 
From command prompt, go to where your mongo installations is situated and run command:

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath C:\path_to_data_folder
```

You may find it useful [Start MondoDB Process](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/)