# MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

if i reinstall mongodb,the code works fine. i wanted an permenant solution

c[error:MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 ]

```
const mongoClient=require("mongodb").MongoClient
const state={
    db:null
}

module.exports.connect=function(done){
    const url="mongodb://localhost:27017"
    const dbname="r-kart"
    mongoClient.connect(url,(err,data)=>{
        if(err) return done(err)
        state.db=data.db(dbname)
        done()
    })
}
module.exports.get=function(){
    return state.db
}
```

Comment: Hope this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523321/mongoerror-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-127017

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: can you share mongod logs and OS version?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit windows

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA mongodb-windows-x86_64-4.4.5-signed

Comment: Most likely your mongo service is not started, see linked question above.

Comment: seems, your mongod service is not running. check in service.msc once

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
Go to the control panel and select admins. tools.
click on "Services" and a list will appear.
look of MongoDB and right click and click on start.

May be this work for you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).