# MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017(Mac workflow)

Tags: mongodb

Same problem as [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523321/mongoerror-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-127017) but for Mac users.

Answer (score -1):

This is the required command on Mac for starting a mongodb server if you installed through homebrew, which is the reccomended installation route on Mongodb's documentation.

```
brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```

Hope this prevented someone from the pain of having to scroll through 20 wrong answers on the other page.

Comment: Not installed via brew. Is there any another solutions?

Comment: Highly reccomend homebrew it takes 5 seconds to install.

Answer (score -1):

I also configured the same error just now. What I found was that you have to install MongoDB as a service, this option can be seen when mongoDB in installed. There are 2 options run mongoDB as a service or run mongoDB as a Local server we have to pick option 1 and things will get configured automatically.