# got and error when i connect mongo db to nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

```const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
.MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

```
const {MongoClient}=require('mongodb');

const url='mongodb://localhost:27017/';

const client= new MongoClient(url);

const dataBase= 'nodejs';

async function getdata(){
    
    let result= await client.connect(); 
     console.log('connect to server')
    let db= result.db(dataBase)
    console.log('2')
    let collection = db.collection('node');
    let response= await collection.find({}).toArray();
    console.log(response)
}

getdata();
```

Comment: Is your mongo server up and running? Doesn't seem like it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change uri to

```
const url='mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/';
```

Comment: but can you explain why we add "mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/" instead of localhost

Comment: 0.0.0.0, in this context, means "all IP addresses on the local machine" (in fact probably, "all IPv4 addresses on the local machine").

Comment: ohh so the local machine ip is not fixed. so is any other option instead of this?

Comment: Please have a look at this it explains in detail

https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1

Answer (score 0):

This happened probably because the **MongoDB** service isn't started.

Follow the below steps to start it:

1. Go to Control Panel and click on Administrative Tools.
   (in Windows the path will be:  `Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools`)
2. Double click on **Services**. A new window opens up.
3. Search **MongoDB.exe**. Right click on it and select *Start*.

The server will start. Now execute `npm start` again and the code might work this time.

The answer from a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523321/mongoerror-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-127017) (I can't comment so I post as an answer)

Comment: sir actiually i follow this process but i not found any file mongodb.exe file in services

Comment: actually i'm using mongoDB 6.0 version. i'm check the version of mongoDB in my pc and not get any version just mongo is not internal and external command