# I am countering an error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 while connecting to mongodb database

Tags: mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I am getting an errror connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 while connect to mongodb database i have installed mongodb compass and the mongodb service is not showing in services of the pc and where the mongodb has been installed in that its not showing the bin and data folder[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSjnq.png)

i have tried to add path to environment variables but the bin and data folder is not available where i have installed the mongodb compass. help me out to resolve this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523321/mongoerror-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-127017). This question get so many answers to cover many scenarios.