# How connect mongoDb in local

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I can connect node.js and mongoDb with my cloud URL but i can't with my localhost url

I install mongoDb ( it's connect on localhost:27017 )

I create :

- database name LMS-v1
- collection name LMS-V1

And when i launch `npm run dev` i got an error

```
[INFO] 14:00:57 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.9.1, typescript ver. 5.2.2)
Server is connected with port 8050
connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
```

You can check [my code on github](https://github.com/wilonweb/LMS-Mern-v1/tree/master)

Comment: Have you done some research about your error ? maybe : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523321/mongoerror-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-127017 BTW, you shouldn't share your `.env` on your githup repo. Ignore it with `.gitignore` configuration file

Comment: thansk 
i find the solution in your link  !!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem
I have to change
`'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Lms-v1'`
into
`mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`