# MongoDB Localhost 27017 Connection with Mongo.Client is not working

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, express, mern

## Cant connect to MongoDB database and store data in localhost:27017 using MongoClient.

## Cant display connection result in the console (both failure and success connections).

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/submit',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body)

  mongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017',function(err,client){

    if(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
    else {
      console.log('connection success')
      client.db('Sample').collection('user').insertOne(req.body)
    }
  })
  res.send('Yeah, got it !')
})

module.exports = router;
```

I tried to connect mongodb and store data using MongoClient. but the data neither stores in the database nor show the connection message inthe console.

when I tried to output to connection result in the console its not showing anything. **its not showing either 'connection success' or 'connection error' message** .The console is empty.

I want to store data using this same method if its possible with required solutions to this issue.

I also wanted to show output in the console whether the connection is success or failure.

I'm using mongodb version 7.0.4 and mongosh 2.0.2 in windows. path is set, mongo also working fine with terminal. how can I solve this issue... ?

...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523321/mongoerror-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-127017). Also, your error message is not helpful at all. Print out the content of `err` for debugging.

Comment: Static text `'connection error'` is not a useful error message. Better print the real error, i.e. `console.log(err.message);`

Comment: @ray I tried those solutions but didn't work. printed err.message, but the real issue isnt that at all. the actual problem is that it shows nothing in my console. not even the error message. even when data is not getting into the database, the error message isnt showing in the console. I've been spending 2 days in this issue and tried all of those similar questions. nothing helped. plz help me figure out this.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I did that. but thats not the real issue here. there is nothing showing in my console, not even the error message when there is issue connecting to the database. help me figure out this. I tried all other similar questions in stackoverflow, nothing worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code once:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/submit', async function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);

  const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
  const dbName = 'Sample';

  try {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    console.log('Connected successfully to server');

    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const result = await db.collection('user').insertOne(req.body);

    console.log('Data inserted successfully:', result.insertedId);
    res.send('Data inserted successfully');

    client.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error:', err);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Yes. it worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77689510/22690700 help me figure out this. its almost the same issue. but I cant solve it.   @Akeel Ahmed Qureshi

Answer (score 0):

Your functions where you use mongo to perform requests need to be asynchronous. Those functions then return `Promises` which you can tackle with the  `.then` method. Hope this helps!

Comment: can you please help me figure out this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/77689510/22690700