# MongoDB connection error. not showing anything in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

I tried to connect mongodb localhost:27017 using MongoClient but I cant connect, and not showing anything in my console. not even the error message. I cant understand the issue in this. plz help me solve this...

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const state = {
  db: null,
  client:null
};
  module.exports.connect = async function (done) {
    const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
    const dbName = "shopping";

    try {
      const mongoClient = await MongoClient.connect(url, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return done(err);
        state.db = data.db(dbName)
        state.client = client
        done()
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error");
      done(err);
    }
  };

  module.exports.get = function () {
    return state.db;
  };
```

Cant connect to mongodb.
I tried all alternatives to localhost port number but thats not the issue. the actual problem here is that its not showing anything in my console. not even the error message. Async and await is used to pause it until connection is success but its not working in this case. There are some errors I cant figure out. plz help me find those.

also, here is a portion of app.js

```
var db = require("./config/connection");

db.connect((err) => {
  if (err) console.log("Error: Connection to db Failed " + err);
  else console.log("Success: Connction to db Success");
});
```

Comment: If that truly is your code, then yeah, no wonder – your `connect` function only assigns `connect` anew, so you should need to call it twice in order for it to do its thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewrited this code with the solution as follows :

**connection.js**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

    const state = {
    db: null,
};

module.exports.connect = async function (done) {
    const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
    const dbName = 'shopping'

    try {
        const mongoClient = await MongoClient.connect(url)
        state.db = mongoClient.db(dbName)
        done()
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error', err)
        done(err)
    }
};

module.exports.get = function () {
    return state.db
}
```

**app.js**

```
var db = require('./config/connection')

db.connect((err)=>{ // (err) coming from connection.js
  if(err) 
  console.log('Error: Connection to db Failed '+err)
  else
  console.log('Success: Connction to db Success')
})
```

Hope this will help others.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).