# How to fix "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017" error when trying to connect to a MongoDB deployment

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB. I came across an issue and the solutions that are already in the web seems to be not fixing the issue. I installed MongoDB Compass (1.41.0) and I'm running windows 10. When I try to connect it displays an error message saying "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017".

[Error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEte9.png)

The solutions in google says to run MongoDB manually in windows services, but MongoDB is not displaying in my services as well. Is there anyone who knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523321/mongoerror-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-127017) There are a lot of scenarios and solutions. Have you checked them out yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have installed mongoDB server. mongoDB compass does not includes mongoDB server which is actual database server. Download it from here and if its already installed make sure its up and running : https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community